# <br> elements being added into <div> as viewed in source

Tags: html, css

There are no br tags in my below code between the beginning of the div tag and table tag but in source several br elements appear.

Here is my code in a .php file.

```
 <div id='tx_addAccountpopup_frame' style = "height: 100px" class='txPopupFrame'>
        <table class="addNewTable"  id = "table" >
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='clearingAccount'>Clearing Acct</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "clearingAccount" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='tposAlloc'>Tpos Alloc</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "tposAlloc" style="text-transform: uppercase" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='tposPortfolio'>Tpos Portfolio</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "tposPortfolio" style="text-transform: uppercase" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='tposGroup'>Tpos Group</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "tposGroup" style="text-transform: uppercase" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='serverCode'>Server Code</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "serverCode" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='clearingFirm'>Clearing Firm</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><select id = "clearingFirm" style="text-transform: uppercase" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='vtk'>VTK</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "vtk" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='clearingAllocAccount'>Clearing Alloc</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "clearingAllocAccount" style="text-transform: uppercase" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='portfolioDesc'>Portfolio Desc</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "portfolioDesc" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='groupDescription'>Group Desc</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "groupDescription" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder"><label for='masterDescription'>Master Desc</label></td><td align = "right" class="spaceUnder"><input type = "text" id = "masterDescription" class="txAddNewField"></td></tr><br>
         </table>
         <button id = "submitNewAccount" onclick ="txSubmitNewAccount()"class = "txDefender_PermissionAddRecordButton" type = "button" width ="100" height="30">Submit</button>

         </div>
```

Here is the source as it appears in Google Chrom dev tools, where you can see br tags added in:

```
<div id="tx_addUserpopup_frame" class="txPopupFrame">
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><table class="addNewTable" id="table" cellspacing="10">

         </table>
         <button id="submitNewUser" onclick="txSubmitNewUser()" class="txDefender_PermissionAddRecordButton" type="button" width="100" height="30">Submit</button>
         </div>
```

What can cause this to happen?  How could I fix it or prevent it?

Comment: `<br>` elements cannot go in between `<tr>` elements (What would be the point...?). In fact, *nothing* can go between `<tr>` elements. Chrome is trying to fix your code by moving the misplaced `<br>` elements to a place where they're valid.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your php you have a `<br>` at every end of the lines in the `<table>`, which is syntactically and semantically wrong. Chrome tries to fix it to be valid code and moves the `<br>`s to the top. Delete all these wrong `<br>`s and it'll be fine.

```
...
<tr><td align="left" class="spaceUnder">[...]</td></tr><br> 
                                                        ^-- cannot go here, remove this
...
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 Yes, you're right. I mixed up the two words... I edited my answer